# fgets trouble shooting

Tags: c, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *pInFile;
    pInFile = fopen("fileName.txt", "r");
    char line[200];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pInFile)) { 
        printf("\n%s", line);
        if (strcmp(line, "C")==1)
            printf("Success");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

So goal of the program is print "Success" after each time it reads the line, which in       this case is "C". For example, my text file looks like this

```
C
C
C
C
```

And I want it to print

```
C
Success
C
Success
C
Success
C
Success
```

However, it is for some reason only printing this

```
C
Success
C
Success
C
Success
C
```

And leaving out the last "Success". I have absolutely no clue why it is doing this.

Comment: Dont' rely on `if (strcmp(line, "C")==1)`. `strcmp()` won't necessarily return +1. It may return any number greater than 0 if the first argument compares greater than the second. Change that to `if (strcmp(line, "C") > 0)`. Oh, and **notice the whitespace.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcmp()` will return 0 if the two strings are equal.

try changing the condition with `strcmp()` to this:

```
if (line[0] == 'C') {
    printf("Success");
}
```

Explanation as to why you are getting the output you posted:

1. fgets on the first line gets the following into `line`:

   ```
   C\n
   ```
2. so when you `strcmp(line, "C") == 1` it succeeds because `strcmp()` returns >0 if 2nd argument > 1st argument.
3. this happens for all the lines except the last one.
4. Therefore in the last line `strcmp()` returns 0 as the strings are equal and you don't print succeed

To solve this do either what Gangadhar suggested in his post or what I showed above.

Comment: When I set it to 0, it does the exact opposite and only prints out success for the final one.

Comment: Could you explain what the line[0] means?

Answer (score 1):

Return value of `strcmp()` is 0 when the strings are equal

Comment: That's what I thought too, but for some reason, when I set it equal to 0, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try comparing with "C\n", fgets might have read the terminating newline character of each line

Comment: you are getting this behaviour because the contents of line is "C\n", fgets() reads the terminating newline character for all lines except the last for which its an EOF. That is why strcmp() is returning 1, because the first string is greater.

Comment: As is said for the final case, it is "C<EOF>" not "C\n". You need to change your approach here: line[0]=='C' might be a better comparison.

Comment: Thats what i said, better is to change your comparison to line[0]=='C' rather than taking <EOF> into account in the condition. <EOF> condition is automatically taken care of by the while(fgets(... )), this should be a better approach. If you still want to explicitly take care of <EOF> there is a defined macro "EOF".

Comment: BTW line is a char array and line{0] is the first character in the array which, as per your text file format will always be 'C'. Hence the comparison line[0]=='C' works.

Comment: How does this EOF work? My final goal is to run this program on a text file with more than just one character, but rather a whole string.

Comment: fgets() will read the trailing newline. In your case a better approach would be to set the trailing \n to \0 as : line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0' and then compare with your normal string as strcmp(line,"your_string")

Answer (score 1):

You can Use [`strncmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp)  and compare 1 character

```
 if (strncmp(line, "C" ,1)==0)
            printf("Success");
```

Comment: @H2CO3 yes but if OP wants to compare more than one character then `strncmp()` would helpful .